# Confidence interval for a linear combination of $\mu$ and $\sigma$

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval

Given $n$ independent observations $X_1,X_2,\ldots X_n\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, where both the variance and the mean are unknown. How can I write down a confidence interval for $\mu+c\sigma$, where $c$ is any real number?

I'd like to add that the case $c=0$ is straightforward and well-known, the same for the confidence interval for the variance.

Comment: (+1) Such a confidence interval is called a "normal tolerance interval."  Usually $\mu+c\sigma$ is expressed in terms of $\Phi(c)$, which is called its "coverage."

Comment: Similar: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/382124/x-1-x-2-dots-x-n-overset-textiid-sim-n-mu-sigma2-derive-a-confide.